# In-app billing - WP7, Android, iOS, OVI and BB

Tags: mobile, in-app-billing

I haven't been able to get clarity on in-app billing systems for the major mobile platforms.

My understanding is that for iOS and Android you are only allowed to use the in-app billing provided by the respective platforms. However www.urbanairship.com claims to provide billing options across both Android and iOS.

What are the billings options / requirements for OVI, BlackBerry and Windows Phone 7?

Answer (score 1):

For *Windows Phone 7* see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh184841(v=VS.92).aspx

> "Unless you have a pre-existing billing relationship with the user,
>   your application may not require the user to provide payment
>   information, within the application experience, to activate, unlock,
>   or extend usage of the application."

No facilites are currently provided by Microsoft to aid with in-app purchases.